# Sign ota package for android

Tags: android, ota

I created signed target file with the help of this command:

```
./build/tools/releasetools/sign_target_files_apks -d ./device/bl/common/security -e app.apk=device/bl/common/security/releasekey -o target.zip signed_target.zip
```

This instruction finished successful.
Now I tried to create signed ota package with the help of this command:

```
./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files -k ./device/bl/common/security/releasekey signed_target.zip ota_signed.zip
```

But I have error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 925, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 893, in main
    WriteFullOTAPackage(input_zip, output_zip, OPTIONS.fota)
  File "./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 464, in WriteFullOTAPackage
    MakeRecoveryPatch(OPTIONS.input_tmp, output_zip, recovery_img, boot_img)
  File "./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 386, in MakeRecoveryPatch
    boot_type, boot_device = common.GetTypeAndDevice("/boot", OPTIONS.info_dict)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

```
./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files -d MMC -k ./device/bl/common/security/releasekey signed_target.zip ota_signed.zip
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of why this will solve the problem. Thank you

Comment: -d MMC set flash or emmc storage